# In codeigniter how can we give special id property to a table using CI's functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

Ordinary table functions like `$this->table->generate()` produces this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how can I produce something like

```
<table border="0" id="myTable" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: by not using a pre-created PHP library

Comment: sorry I'm just being a dick. But if I may ask, why are you using a library rather than coding your own solutions?

Comment: I am using CI, and trying to use it with full performance. and also I am giving credits whoever writes those libraries.

Comment: @techjunkie.css, there is nothing wrong with using CI's table helper, bluebrain just doesn't know how to configure it. The table helper is best for quick outputting of data (if you are developing and don't want to type everything out but have a nice output of your data).

Comment: @bluebrain, consider in the future looking at the CI documentation, it is very good, and this question is answered in their table section: [http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html)

Comment: current link: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
    $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => 
'<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" id="YOUR_ID" class="mytable">' );

    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 

echo $this->table->generate();
```

UPDATE 1:

```
$tmpl = array (
                    'table_open'          => '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" id="YOUR_ID" class="mytable">',

                    'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
                    'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                    'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
                    'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                    'row_start'           => '<tr>',
                    'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                    'cell_start'          => '<td>',
                    'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                    'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                    'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                    'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
                    'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                    'table_close'         => '</table>'
              );

$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

Ref: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Comment: this worked, but I have one further question. if you can answer it, I would be happier. here is my further question:
your way of sending template only includes 'table_open'. does your sending template effect other properties like 'row_start' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_template()` function to set the `table_open` value to the output you need.

```
$template = array('table_open' => '<table border="0" id="myTable" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">');
$this->table->set_template($template);
```